# Check if string is in another column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my DF

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['[7]', '[30]', '[0]', '[7]'], 'col2': ['[0%, 7%]', '[30%]', '[30%, 7%]', '[7%]']})

col1    col2    
[7]     [0%, 7%]
[30]    [30%]
[0]     [30%, 7%]
[7]     [7%]
```

The aim is to check if col1 value is contained in col2
below is what I've tried

```
df['test'] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x.col1) in str(x.col2), axis=1)
```

Below is the expected output

```
col1    col2       col3
[7]     [0%, 7%]   True
[30]    [30%]      True
[0]     [30%, 7%]  False
[7]     [7%]       True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also replace the square brackets with word boundaries `\b` and use `re.search` like in

```py
import re
#...
df.apply(lambda x: bool(re.search(x['col1'].replace("[",r"\b").replace("]",r"\b"), x['col2'])), axis=1)
# => 0     True
#    1     True
#    2    False
#    3     True
#    dtype: bool
```

This will work because `\b7\b` will find a match in `[0%, 7%]` as `7` is neither preceded nor followed with letters, digits or underscores. There won't be any match found in `[30%, 7%]` as `\b0\b` does not match a zero after a digit (here, `3`).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) for get numbers, reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), so possible compare by [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df['test'] = (df['col2'].str.extractall('(\d+)')[0].unstack()
                        .isin(df['col1'].str.strip('[]'))
                        .any(axis=1))
print (df)
   col1       col2   test
0   [7]   [0%, 7%]   True
1  [30]      [30%]   True
2   [0]  [30%, 7%]  False
3   [7]       [7%]   True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the numbers on both columns and `join`, then check if there is at least one match per id using `eval`+`groupby`+`any`:

```
(df['col2'].str.extractall('(?P<col2>\d+)').droplevel(1)
   .join(df['col1'].str[1:-1])
   .eval('col2 == col1')
   .groupby(level=0).any()
)
```

output:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach:

```
import ast

# convert to integer list
col2_lst = df["col2"].str.replace("%", "").apply(ast.literal_eval)

# check list containment
df["col3"] = [all(bi in a for bi in b)  for a, b in zip(col2_lst, df["col1"].apply( ast.literal_eval)) ]

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   col1       col2   col3
0   [7]   [0%, 7%]   True
1  [30]      [30%]   True
2   [0]  [30%, 7%]  False
3   [7]       [7%]   True
```